# Is there an API for SMART?

Tags: hard-drive, nas, c-api

Developing a NAS system at the moment and I want to use SMART to monitor the state of the harddrive in the NAS. I have looked at tools like smartmontools smartctl and smartd however I want to have more control over the what I tell the NAS to react to when different errors occur. smartd supports running scripts but it is not preferable. Is there an api preferable in c that one can use to speak with a SMART HDD?

Comment: Also interested, any progress ?